# How to find number of injections from a finite set A to finite set B where |A| < |B|?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I need to find number of injections from a finite set A to finite set B where |A| < |B|. How could i do that? I don't understand what does |A| and |B| mean

Comment: Number of elements in the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|A|$ means the *cardinality* of set $A$. We have $|B|$ options for the first element of $A$, $|B|-1$ options after that for the second element and so on (if we want to make this an injection), so the number of injections is
$$|B|(|B|-1)\cdots(|B|-|A|+1)=\frac{|B|!}{(|B|-|A|)!}$$

Comment: thanks. and what does number of injections means here? I know what does injective function means, but what is injection in relations?

Comment: @french_fries There is no relation here, but an injection is a kind of function.

Comment: got you, and what is a formula for multiplications?)

Comment: @french_fries Is this not just the multiplication principle?

Comment: its a number of permutations, got it